# Updating properties of a class c#

Tags: c#

I have the following POCO in my project:

```
 public class FileTranslationData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public string FileJSONLocation { get; set; }
    public int TranslationRetries { get; set; }
    public string TranslationStatus { get; set; }
    public string TranslationId { get; set; }
    public string FileTranslationURL { get; set; }
    public string TranslatedFileURL { get; set; }
    public string ProcessStatus { get; set; }
    public int FileDownLoadRetries { get; set; }
    public int FileUploadRetries { get; set; }
    public int RetryDuration { get; set; }
    public string Errors { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastRetryTime { get; set; }
    public string StatusLog { get; set; }
}
```

Which I use to save data to and from a LiteDB to help maintain state of file progression through my process.  If I need to update certain properties of this class, I retrieve it from the database, make the changes and then resave to the database, no problem.  I use this class to detect changes in the object (pulled and modified from another answer):

```
 public static List<string> GetChangeProperties<T>(T a, T b) where T:class 
    {
       if(a != null && b != null)
        {
            if(object.Equals(a,b))
            {
                return new List<string>();
            }
            var allProperties = a.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            return allProperties.Where(p => !object.Equals(p.GetValue(a), p.GetValue(b))).Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            var aText = $"{(a == null ? ("\"" + nameof(a) + "\"" + " was null") : "")}";
            var bText = $"{(b == null ? ("\"" + nameof(b) + "\"" + " was null") : "")}";
            var bothNull = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(aText) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bText);
            throw new ArgumentNullException(aText + (bothNull ? ", " : "") + bText);
        }
    }
```

This will return a list of properties that have changed between the objects. Once I have the list of changed properties, I only want to update the properties in the first object that have changed based on the 2nd object before re-saving the update back to the database.  I'm looking for help on a better way of changing the properties than using a switch statement and checking all the properties if they are different and only changing the properties that have changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why bother detecting which properties have changed? Why not just save the new object? So long as they have the same Id, it should overwrite the old object, right?

Comment: Yes.  Good point.  I think I got off into the weeds on this one and was trying to over engineer it.  Thanks.